# Group first folder and the following files in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regex to group the root folder of a package and to group the rest of the files in it.

I tried the following `@package\/(.*)\/(\/*.+)$` with the test string `@package/util/src/index.js`:
[Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kfNc.png)

But instead of grouping `util/src` and `index.js` I want to group for `util` and `src/index.js`. I thought the `/` between the groups in my regex would match on the first `/`. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern like this to not cross the first `/` and then capture the rest of the line using `(.+)$` without optional repeating `\/*`

```
@package\/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCuRhL/1)